# Postfix Header_Checks Reject Legitimate Mail (CnetOS 7 + Postfix 2.10.1)

Tags: postfix

I use Postfix to block terms in headers and bodies.  In few cases, it blocks legitimate mails because the term used is present in a long string (probably an id or reference or a coded string).

For example:

/AQHV/ REJECT  SPAM RULE #5

Emails containing the following text in their headers are rejected.  Because the characters "AQHV" are in the one of the headers:-

Thread-Index: **AQHV**SEXnJ2u6futfzU6u85aNv7EgTg

I have tried to add a space before + after the term AQHV, like so:-

/ AQHV/ REJECT  SPAM RULE #5

/AQHV / REJECT  SPAM RULE #6

This error occurs:

postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/header_checks.db: duplicate entry: "/"

How can I tell Postfix to treat the term "AQHV" as a separate word only, and not as part of a string?

Thanks in advance!

tripleee:  apologies for the comments - still struggling with these forums.

I have decided to uninstall Postfix and reinstall it again. It might solve this problem.  I will accept your answer.  Many thanks.

Comment: The error message sounds vaguely like you put these in the wrong file or something. Can you show how you have configured this db?

Comment: They are put in /etc/postfix/header_checks file.  Then:
# postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
# service postfix restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `/\bAHQV\b/`. Here `\b` is a regex word boundary marker.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This /\bAQHV\b/ hasn't worked for me.   Tested an email with   subject AQHV and it was not rejected.  I am not using regex.  As explained in the post, they are just terms followed by REJECT

Comment: Correction: I meant  /\AQHV\b/ hasn't worked for me.  The previous one was a typo

Comment: Then switch to regexp, or probably preferably the pcre filter type. The syntax with slashes is specific to the regex filters.

Comment: The 2 lines were already added to main.cf:-

header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks

Please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Just to add that the command: postconf -m shows that both pcre + regexp are installed.

Comment: Probably edit your question instead of heaping comments below this specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include this in main.cf:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Run these commands, assuming header_checks is in /etc/postfix/.

```
postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
postfix reload
```

To deal with spaces in regex/pcre, you can comment them out. For example, if you wanted to reject any email with a space in the header, you could put this in header_checks:

```
/\ / REJECT NO SPACES ALLOWED!!!!
```

So, if you wanted to just block an email with a line in the header that contained AHQV, but just the string AHQV, not AHQV as a substring in a larger string, then this is the regex you need:

```
/\ AHQV\ / REJECT NO AHQV PLS
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).